How to run a bash command in a Google Cloud Run Job?
I'm trying to execute the following bash command as a Google Cloud Run Job from the Google Cloud Console: dbt run -s tag:client.
For that, I'm passing container arguments, while keeping the entrypoint untouched:

I've pushed the following Dockerfile to Artifact Registry for that:
FROM python:3.11

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/

RUN dbt deps

ENTRYPOINT ["dbt"]

Executing docker run locally works fine:
docker run \  
 data-warehouse-2 \
 run -s tag:client   

However, when I pass the following arguments to the Cloud Run Job:
    args:
    - run
    - -s
    - tag:client

I get the error
terminated: Application failed to start: "/usr/local/bin/dbt": exec format error

I've tried with many different entrypoints and different combinations of the args:
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "dbt \"$@\"", "--"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "dbt"]

And none of them work. How can I run the desired command as a Cloud Run Job?

How do you invoke your Cloud Run Job? Do you use parameter override? Do you set static params? do you change the entry point?

IIUC tag:epbs is the value you want attributed to the -s (--select) flag. What happens if you replace the two lines - -s and - tag:epbs with the single line -s tag:epbs or --select=tag:epbs?

@guillaumeblaquiere I've added a screenshot of how im doing it

@DazWilkin In the GC console, as soon as you press space, it creates a new argument. I've tried using " and ` to indicate the same argument and it breaks the arguments too

It's difficult to repro your issue as I don't use dbt and it appears non-trivial to create. I wrote a very basic program that emits command-line arguments and used Cloud Console to create 2 jobs. The first uses arguments run,-s,foo:bar. The second uses arguments run,--select=foo:bar. Both of these run as expected. I encourage you to try the second approach per my previous comment. Alternatively, I encourage you to consider using the CLI (gcloud) as this will permit you to specify everything more effectively including the --args.

exec format error may mean that the binary is for the wrong architecture. Are you building and testing your image on an ARM machine, by chance?

Just making sure, are you using an ARM based machine (M1)? If so, refer to the following official documents:
Container failed to start

Note: If you build your container image on a ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. To solve this issue, build your image using Cloud Build.

Supported languages and images

Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit. Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format.

You should build your Docker container with the --platform linux/amd64 flag before deploying the image to Cloud Run:
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t image-name:v1.1 .
You can find similar answers in post1 & post2 for more details.
